# Version of the parent object does not change when its child object's state changes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am using Hibernate3
I have a simple one to many relationship(Parent object has as set of child objects)
if the child objects are added/removed, the version of the parent object is updated where as if the state of the child object is changed, the version of the parent is not getting updated.

Here is the mapping - 
Category.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="net.codejava.hibernate">
<class name="Category" table="CATEGORY">
    <id name="id" column="CATEGORY_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="NAME" />
    <version name="version" type="integer" column="version" unsaved-value="null" />
    <set name="products" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" />
        <one-to-many class="Product"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

Product.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="net.codejava.hibernate">
<class name="Product" table="PRODUCT">
    <id name="id" column="PRODUCT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <version name="version" type="integer" column="version" unsaved-value="null" />
    <property name="name" column="NAME" />
    <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" />
    <property name="price" column="PRICE" type="float" />

    <many-to-one name="category" class="Category"
        column="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

When the Product changes, Product.version is updated properly but the Category.version remains the same.

I assume this is a cross cutting concern and there has to be a plausible solution for this. I did a lot of searching and could not find one. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just a limitation of the way hibernate works, I'm afraid. The only solution is to change it on both sides when you need to make a change.

You could also refresh the parent, but bear in mind that that will hit the database.

Comment: So.. there is not way to update the parent's version when the state of the child(one-to-many) changes?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a subjective opinion, but to me it seems logical this way. However, one common way of handling this is to have something like `lastUpdated` field on parent entity, which you would set each time before calling `update` on it. This can be done in `@PrePersist` and/or `@PreUpdate`, and it would ensure that entity version changes whenever you update it, regardless of what changes are made to it or its relations.

Comment: Yeah... I thought of it.. But it seems Like a hacky way of getting that done. Wanted to know if there are any better approaches.

Comment: Just found [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5990827/4074715), you might try it. Other than that, I can't think of any other non-hacky solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go ahead and do the dirty check myself specific to the business case to see if the versions have changed.

Comment: I've tried the @PreUpdate solution but it did not work for me.  The parent is not actually calling PreUpdate if its only the child that has changed.  It's possible I did something wrong but I thought I would warn people that this might not work.