# Envers audits parent entity when inserting a sub-entity, but not when updating

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a Store/Clerks classes in my application, that are related via the "storeId" foreign key in the "clerks" DB table , and with the Hibernate annotations given in the following code:

Store.java :

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="stores")
Public Class Store {
    private Set<Clerks> clerks;
//....
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "store")
public Set<Clerks> getClerks() {
    return clerks;
}
}
```

Clerk.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="clerks")
Public Class Clerk {        
    private Store store;
//....
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "storeId",referencedColumnName = "storeId")
public Store getStore() {
    return store;
}
}
```

When I'm inserting (persisting) the new Clerk, Envers makes entries in audit tables of both entities ("stores_aud" and "clerks_aud") .
But, when I'm updating the existing Clerk, it only makes an entry in the "clerks_aud" table.

Can anyone explain to me, why this is happening, and how to enforce Envers to behave the same in both of the cases (insert and update)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

When you add a new `Clerk` to `Store`, `Store#clerks`collection is altered, which results in new audit entry for `Store`. When `Clerk` is changed, no fields of `Store` are changed, so no audit entry is generated for it, just for `Clerk`.

If you want to also generate audit entry for `Store` when `Clerk` is updated, you will have to handle it yourself. One common solution for this is to have something like `lastUpdated` column on `Store`, which you would update whenever something has changed.

Comment: Hvala Pedja ;)

This is very helpful, but the only thing is that I actually have a more complex structure, with a lot of other sub entities related to "store" and I have a requirement that entities keep their own "lastUpdated" separated.
So, I guess the other way of solving it is to make my own Listener class, right?

Comment: Nema na čemu :) Take a look at [this similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250271/version-of-the-parent-object-does-not-change-when-its-child-objects-state-chang). Your options are limited, weather you can use "lastUpdated" or not depends on your requirements. To keep it isolated, maybe you could add another column which you would update when some logic is satisfied (some specific child changed, etc.), but that has a hacky sense to it.