# Optimistic Locking in Hibernate does not change the value of the version-column in the table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, liquibase, optimistic-locking

To implement optimistic locking in Spring Boot project, I added a field with the @Version annotation:

```
package com.example.my_api.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client {

    // ...

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    // ...

}
```

Then i added a version-column in the corresponding table, using Liqubase-migration:
[image]

And now, I'm testing with Postman. First I create a new client with a POST-request, then I update its data (name, age) with a PUT-request. If I understand correctly, when we update the entity, it should automatically increase the value of the version-field by 1. But in my case this does not happen:
[image]

The value is 0 and it is not incremented. Can you help me? What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer from this similar question: [How to increase a version field on save in Hibernate regardless if dirty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990766/how-to-increase-a-version-field-on-save-in-hibernate-regardless-if-dirty-or-not)

> You can use Hibernate interceptors to update the version number of the
> master record when you identify that detail has changed.
>
> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html
>
> One limitation is that this solution is specific to Hibernate. JPA
> also allows event-driven logic using annotations (e.g. PostPersist,
> PostUpdate, etc...) but these methods don't give you access to the
> underlying session (and, more importantly, the documentation cautions
> you from using these methods to modify session data). I've typically
> used interceptors to perform auditing, but they could easily be
> extended to update a version number when a record is altered.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and mine was because the data was not flushed to the database prior to the second DML.

To test, i changed my repository and `extends JpaRepository` instead of `extends CrudRepository`. Then instead of doing `save`, i did `saveAndFlush`. My `version` field was updated as expected.